# How to create a realm transaction on the same thread from several webservice results

Tags: ios, swift, realm

We have a big amount of data to insert into a realm database. The data are coming from **several webservices** for a total amount of 100Mb to **1Gb**.
We need to store each result from network with **a transaction**. If all the webservices are **downloaded successfully**, after a post-process we **commit the database**.

Due to the fact that realm for that transaction requires to work **on the same thread and that the webservice are asynchrone**, the problem we are facing is that we are not able to **call the same thread** after a webservice result, how can we manage to handle this situation?

Note:

- We cannot load all the data in memory -> the huge amount of data is putting at risk the memory exception
- Storing the result of webservice response in files and loading file by file are not very efficient -> we did this but the performance are bad (we spend 30% of processing the management of the file decoding…)

Comment: I would create a temporal realm (you can specify the path of the realm in the `Realm.Configuration` when create the `Realm`) and when all the transactions commit, merge the temporal to the real.

Comment: @hfehrmann merging two realm db, requires to fetch all objects from base 1 to base 2 and then insert them. Handling corner case and issues. Pretty complex solution IMOO